# Compile error when trying to use std::result_of

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

I want to deduce the return type of a function coming as a template parameter. Consider the following code:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct Result {};

Result foo() { return Result{}; }

template<typename Factory>
void check(Factory) {
    using ActualResult = typename std::result_of<Factory()>::type;
    static_assert(std::is_same<Result, ActualResult>::value, "");
}

int main() {
    check(foo);
}
```

This works as expected. However, if I change the parameter of `check()` to `const Factory&`, then it does not compile. The error from gcc is:

```
prog.cc: In instantiation of 'void check(const Factory&) [with Factory = Result()]':
prog.cc:14:14:   required from here
prog.cc:9:66: error: function returning a function
     using ActualResult = typename std::result_of<Factory()>::type;
                                                                  ^
prog.cc:10:65: error: function returning a function
     static_assert(std::is_same<Result, ActualResult>::value, "");
                                                                 ^
```

What's the problem here? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions (just like arrays) can neither be passed as prvalue arguments or returned as prvalues.

Therefore, `template <typename Factory> void check(Factory)`, which takes a prvalue argument, will cause `foo` to decay to the function pointer, and `check(foo)` will cause `Factory` to be deduced as `Result (*)()`. Finally, `result_of<Factory()>` gives the result of calling the callable type that is the function pointer with no arguments.

When you change `check` to `check(const Factory&)`, the function takes an lvalue, and so there is no decay, and `Factory` is deduced as the function type `Result()`. This is not a type that you are allowed to pass to `result_of`*, which requires either a callable type or a reference to a function. That is, you should use `result_of<Factory&()>` in that case.

<sub>*) In C++11. The rules for `result_of` may have been relaxed in later revisions, and C++17 deprecates `result_of`.</sub>

Comment: @petersohn: Ah yes, that actually works in both cases.